# how do i insert javascript code into colorbox?

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I need to execute a javascript into a colorbox modal window.

I've heard about placing an onComplete callback but i've no idea on how to write it...i'm totally noobie to jquery/javascript.

Can anyone explain me step by step ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
$('a#example').colorbox({onComplete:function(){
  // put your code here.
}});
```

Comment: Thank you Jack for your answer.